# Riemann Integrals - Evaluating Summations

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Can anyone help me solve these please?

I tried following steps given by a teacher:

Defining the partitions in the form of c+k/n
Take out 1/n width
Creating the function
What do we input? The Upper bound? The Geometric average?
Define the height of the rectangle in terms of some function of the input
Show that the summation is the Riemann sum for the integral and evaluate

However, I haven't been able to solve it after two hours :( Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Answer (score 1):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a)/n^{a+1}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^a}{n^{a+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(\frac{k}{n})^a\\
&=&\int_0^1x^adx=\frac{1}{a+1},\\
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}((2n+1)^{-1}+(2n+2)^{-1}+\cdots+(3n)^{-1}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2n+k}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2+\frac{k}{n}}\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x}dx=\ln\frac{3}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: thank you so so much!